# Deleting Rows in VBA if it satisfies some criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Please find the related workbook attached below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zlwz12sigx5w6le/deleting%20rows.xlsm

So there are 3 columns, column A is dates, column B is values related to a bank and column C is "exitflag". Essentially what I want to do is the following:

If the number is 1 under "exitflag", then I want to delete the entire row, eg, in row 2, "exitflag" takes on a value of 1, so I want the entire row deleted such that both the date and the value related to the bank is also deleted. By delete I mean I want the row removed so that the next row "shifts" up so that no empty row appears. Also note that there is also the number 1 under column B, eg, row 201, I do not want to delete those, I only want the rows deleted where exitflag has a value of 1.

I have written the following code but for some reason I don't think it works (or if it does work, I have to keep running it over and over, it doesn't do what I want in one go):

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    For Each R In Selection.Rows

        For Each c In R.Cells(1, 3)
            If c.Value = 1 Then
                R.Delete
            End If
        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Also preferably I would like the code to be a "selection." code rather than specifying a range as I would like to reuse the code on other datasets but with different number of rows.

Much appreciated for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite common mistake made also by good programmers. When deleting **you should start with the last position and count backwards.** If not, you will remove one element of the collection changing the order of other elements within collection. As a result you (rather) won't delete all required collection items.

Without looking into your sheet this could be a solution (not tested):

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim i as Long
    For i= Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

        For Each c In Selection.Rows(i).Cells(1, 3)
            If c.Value = 1 Then
                c.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                Exit For  'can be important
            End If
        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Yep - counting backwards is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim flag As Range, exitFlags As Range

    Set exitFlags = Selection //NOTE: just select the ExitFlags column

        For Each flag In exitFlags
            If flag = 1 Then
                flag.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```